# How can I get the i-tec USB 3.0 Docking Station running under Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I want to get this [i-tec USB 3.0 Docking Station](https://i-tec.cz/de/produkt/u3hdmidvidock-3/) running with Ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded the drivers for Ubuntu from [here](https://i-tec.cz/wp-content/uploads/man_dri/DisplayLink_Ubuntu.zip), untipped the file and followed the install instructions in the `READ ME.pdf` (with content similar to [this one](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu))

I got this output of the installation script:

```
Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 19.04 sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.2.14.run
[sudo] password for florian: 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.2.14  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.2.14 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Installing EVDI kernel module to kernel tree
EVDI kernel module built successfully
Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager
Installing libraries
Installing firmware packages
Installing licence file
Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/4xxx/5xxx/6xxx devices

Please read the FAQ
http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu
Installation complete!
```

The device is connected via USB:

```
$ lsusb | grep DisplayLink
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink
```

However seems like it should contain something like this which is missing in my output:

```
Starting DLM upstart job
displaylink start/running, process XXXX
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: I see a line in your output about the FAQ and troubleshooting Ubuntu. That FAQ has a section called "My DisplayLink device does not work on Ubuntu" with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Don't forget to reboot after installing the driver.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW. [i-tec USB 3.0 / USB-C / Thunderbolt 3 Dual Display Docking Station](https://i-tec.cz/en/produkt/cadual4kdock-2/) works for me with Ubuntu 19.04 and [DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) on Dell XPS 13 9365 with Intel 615

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 615 (rev 02)
```

See the log below (it seems to be identical to the log from 18.04)

```
$ ./displaylink-driver-5.2.14.run 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.2.14  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.2.14 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 19.04
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Installing EVDI kernel module to kernel tree
EVDI kernel module built successfully
Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager
Installing libraries
Installing firmware packages
Installing licence file
Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/4xxx/5xxx/6xxx devices

Please read the FAQ
http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu
Installation complete!

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 17e9:6000 DisplayLink
```

2 external monitors are detected:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders -v
xrandr program version       1.5.0
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 2 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x23f cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 2: id: 0x1f9 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Server reports RandR version 1.5
```

- Only 2 external monitors can be connected to this dock. 2-port splitter connected to any DP, or HDMI of the dock does not work.
- Charging does not work. There is a workaround. Charging works when connected via "i-tec USB-C Travel Adapter PD/Data".

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I had to install `dkms` before running the install script with `sudo apt-get install dkms`.