# xps-13 lts upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, lts, xps

Is there a supported method for upgrading a Dell XPS-13 9370 from LTS 18.04 to 20.04?  Of course I'd like all my device drivers and installed apps to not break as a result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I smoothly upgrade from one LTS to next LTS release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717827/can-i-smoothly-upgrade-from-one-lts-to-next-lts-release)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that thread.  Interesting that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  So I'd feel a lot more confident if I heard from someone with my exact hardware/software config who attempted this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_or_19.10) says

> You can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from either Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu 19.10.

FWIW. The installation (not upgrade) of Xubuntu 20.04 to my Dell XPS-13 9365 completed flawlessly. To be on the save side, I've decided to keep my previous Ubuntu along with the original Windows in partitions 4,5 and install 20.04 into the partition 6.

```
shell> lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop1         7:1    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop2         7:2    0 154.3M  1 loop /snap/chromium/1123
loop3         7:3    0  27.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/7264
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  39.6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  39.1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0  39.1G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0 104.5G  0 part /export
└─nvme0n1p8 259:8    0  15.6G  0 part [SWAP]
```

HW support of XPS 13 is included out of the box. All is working except the fingerprint ([supported](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/138a:0091), but I haven't found any GUI in Xfce). Kernel 5.4 is great. Average core temperature dropped by 10-20 degrees! My 19.10 Xubuntu desktop was running on 60-70 C average. The core temperature is now under 40 degree C when idle and 50 degree C on 30% CPU usage (Cooler Master pad; 20 C room temperature). The graphics (Intel 615) is faster and smoother running with 3 external display on [DisplayLink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163991/how-can-i-get-the-i-tec-usb-3-0-docking-station-running-under-ubuntu-18-04/1176574#1176574).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vlad, it's encouraging... I would like to try burning/booting the live CD first to feel more confident prior... need to see if I can attach my old usb cd drive to this laptop first... mainly because I've read posts from folks who cannot boot after attempting [earlier] LTS upgrades.

Comment: It's possible to create a bootable USB from the ISO. `"ddrescue path/to/.iso /dev/sdx --force -D"` See [Create Bootable USB Media From ISO](https://fossbytes.com/create-bootable-usb-media-from-iso-ubuntu/).

Comment: I booted into the live CD from my xps-13.  Wireless works; printer was found; however none of the alphanumeric keys work on the keyboard...but arrow and tab and alt-tab all work [as well as trackpad]...?!  Very strange, the onboard keyboard display shows them pressed in keyboard preferences.  But nothing appears in browser [Firefox] or the terminal app.  So I am postponing the upgrade until I figure this out.

Comment: This is really strange. I haven't had any issues. I wonder there is such a difference between 9370 and 9365?

Comment: Turns out the keyboard problem was not related to 20.04 LTS... I think it got into a weird state due to touch screen.  Rebooting fixed it.  From my limited testing, 20.04 seems to run fine on my 9370.

Answer (score 1):

I had XPS-13 9370 with 18.04 installed, accidentally installed 19, and was offered to upgrade to 20.04, which seems to be running more of less fine now on the laptop.

Can someone explain how to add the Dell firmware updates?

I think the solution is somewhere here: http://oem.archive.canonical.com/dists/?C=M;O=D

```
root@xray:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven InRelease
Ign:2 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem InRelease                                                                                                                         
Ign:3 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://files2.eid.belgium.be/debian eoan InRelease                                                                                                                                    
Hit:5 http://files.eid.belgium.be/debian eoan InRelease                                                                                                                                     
Hit:6 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-oem InRelease                                                                                                                          
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                
Hit:8 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell InRelease                                                                                                                
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                                           
Get:10 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem Release [4,171 B]                                                                                   
Hit:11 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-dell InRelease                                                                                                     
Get:12 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem Release.gpg [287 B]                                                           
Ign:13 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-dell-service InRelease                                                                                              
Get:14 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven Release [4,221 B]                                   
Get:15 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service Release [4,240 B]                             
Err:16 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-dell-service Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.89.6 80]
Get:17 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven Release.gpg [287 B]
Get:18 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service Release.gpg [287 B]
Hit:19 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Ign:12 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem Release.gpg
Ign:17 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven Release.gpg
Ign:18 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service Release.gpg
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,628 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,124 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,603 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,016 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,794 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [44.3 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [14.3 MB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]                                                                                                        
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74.7 kB]                                                                                                            
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]                                                                                                            
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]                                                                                                            
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48.4 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [23.1 kB]                                                                                                       
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [192 kB]                                                                                                        
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [214 B]                                                                                                       
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 128x128 Icons [326 kB]                                                                                                      
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,136 B]                                                                                                     
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [77.5 kB]                                                                                                      
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [142 kB]                                                                                                      
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [71.7 kB]                                                                                                     
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [176 kB]                                                                                               
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [88.3 kB]                                                                                                 
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [153 kB]                                                                                                  
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                  
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [368 kB]                                                                                                
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4,820 B]                                                                                               
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11.6 kB]                                                                                                   
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [3,312 B]                                                                                                    
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [3,892 B]                                                                                                   
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]                                                                                            
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                  
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]                                                                                               
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 128x128 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [480 B]                                                                                               
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [310 kB]                                                                                                          
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [187 kB]                                                                                                           
Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]                                                                                                   
Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [44.1 kB]                                                                                                     
Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]                                                                                             
Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages [2,268 B]                                                                                                    
Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3,096 B]                                                                                                   
Get:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe Translation-en [1,448 B]                                                                                                   
Get:68 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,972 B]                                                                                            
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2,809 B]                                                                                               
Get:70 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [3,943 B]                                                                                               
Get:71 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                
Get:72 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [6,807 B]                                                                                             
Get:73 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [224 B]                                                                                               
Get:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]                                                                                             
Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [28.9 kB]                                                                                                  
Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages [6,356 B]                                                                                                   
Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [7,664 B]                                                                                                  
Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [324 B]                                                                                              
Get:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [42.8 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [18.0 kB]                                                                                                     
Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [22.6 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.7 kB]                                                                                             
Get:83 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,321 B]                                                                                                
Get:84 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [10.1 kB]                                                                                                
Get:85 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                 
Get:86 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [11.2 kB]                                                                                              
Get:87 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1,768 B]                                                                                              
Get:88 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,172 B]                                                                                                  
Get:89 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Translation-en [540 B]                                                                                                    
Get:90 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]                                                                                              
Get:91 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [55.8 kB]                                                                                                         
Get:92 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [147 kB]                                                                                                         
Get:93 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [51.1 kB]                                                                                                        
Get:94 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [21.2 kB]                                                                                                 
Get:95 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [8,330 B]                                                                                                    
Get:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [12.1 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:97 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                                                                     
Get:98 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [27.9 kB]                                                                                                  
Get:99 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3,428 B]                                                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                               
E: The repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates focal-dell-service Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/oem.archive.canonical.com_updates_dists_bionic-oem_Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
E: The repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-oem Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dell.archive.canonical.com_updates_dists_bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven_Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
E: The repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-beaver-three-eyed-raven Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dell.archive.canonical.com_updates_dists_bionic-dell-service_Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
E: The repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates bionic-dell-service Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

[image]

update: 20.04 is not supported (yet) by Dell:

[image]